# Yup: Validating Array of Strings That Can Be Empty

Tags: formik, yup

I have the following as a form field type for Formik:

```
interface FormFields {
  groups: string[];
}
```

I'm trying to pass a Yup schema that will validate the above: the fact that it can be an empty array (must be defined) but can also contain strings.

The following is not working:

```
const schema = Yup.object({
  groups: Yup.array().defined()
}).defined();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 48):

I found out that empty arrays are truthy. And after finally finding the yup docs [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup#api). I used the `.min(num, message)` method of `Yup.array()`

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  stringArray: Yup.array().min(1, messageHere);
});
```

you can also check if the values of your array contains strings using the `array().of()`

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  stringArray: Yup.array().of(Yup.string());
});
```

Comment: But ``` const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  phoneNumber:Yup.array().of(Yup.string())

})

schema.isValid({
  phoneNumber:[1]
}).then(valid=>{
  console.log(valid);  //gives true
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
groups: yup
    .array(
      yup.string().required(),
    )
    .min(1)
```

But you can use this format too:

```
groups: yup
        .array().of(yup.string())
        .min(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example. tested

```
let yup = require('yup')

const tSchema = yup.object().shape({
  groups: yup.array().notRequired(),
})

const u = tSchema.cast({
  groups: [],
  
})

console.log(u)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the array is actually required. It must be defined, and when there are indeed values inside it, they must be strings.