# Yup validation -- making sure an array contains at least one item

Tags: javascript, yup

I have an array like this

```
{
    array: ["1", "4"]
}
```

but I want to add a yup validation to it -- if the array is empty - so at least one item is in the array

I've tried something like this - but its not working

```
myArray: yup.array().min(1). required("at least one item needs to be here")
```

are empty arrays always truthy?
[Yup: Validating Array of Strings That Can Be Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169455/yup-validating-array-of-strings-that-can-be-empty)

but this sandbox seems to work?
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-khorana-3pjmq?file=/src/index.js

---

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-rgb-b2sct

here is the formik formframe work - with checkboxes -- shown - but when the checkboxes are not selected aka value is an empty array -- the error should show - but it doesnt?

Answer (score 12):

What you did is already correct and expected. I'm not sure what's your confusion.

If the code is:

```
import "./styles.css";
//import { object, array } from "yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const mySchema = yup.object({
  myArray: yup.array().min(1, "at least 1").required("required")
});

console.log("[]", mySchema.isValidSync({ myArray: [] }));

console.log(
  '["John"]',
  mySchema.isValidSync({
    myArray: ["John"]
  })
);

console.log(
  '["John", "Doe"]',
  mySchema.isValidSync({
    myArray: ["John", "Doe"]
  })
);
```

It returns:

```
[] false
["John"] true
["John", "Doe"] true
```

If I changed the line to
`myArray: yup.array().min(2, "at least 2").required("required")`

Then it returns:

```
[] false
["John"] false
["John", "Doe"] true
```

Comment: Its not working - in my code base -- I am building a form framework -- with formik - but this doesn't seem to work with the empty array value - its like it doesn't show an error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-rgb-b2sct  -- so when the checkboxes doesn't have at least ONE checked - the error should show - but it doesn't

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-stonebraker-q5zd8  -- this features the bug I'm trying to solve

Comment: Something is wrong with your `<FieldHandler/>` the way you created the checkbox schema. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-snyder-gqemh?file=/src/_Globals/GeneralFormik/GeneralFormik.js:1111-1145) in my `console.log` between the `validationSchema` in formik and the values that is generated in formik. Try to see the console then change the value of the checkbox, you will see that you are saving the value of your whole checkbox in `checkbox_option1` key only.

Comment: Then following your second sandbox, if i put the correct validation as seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dubinsky-0rz1t?file=/index.js). Formik is not submitting if at least 1 checkbox is not ticked (see `console.log` if it goes to submission or not). Thus yup is working as expected.

Comment: -- but that didn't work in codesandbox.io/s/lively-rgb-b2sct

Comment: I managed to get this working with this validation -- "validation": yup.mixed().test('arraySize', "Must have at least one checked", value => value.length > 0)